# how to check null condition on plsql cursor column?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am creating a cursor on a query getting all the columns from a table. in a loop i am using each column and printing it out. I wanted to know any easy way to check whether a column has any value or not. if a column in a row is null, put "NULL". I know I can use if condition to check each and every column in a row from the cursor in a for loop. but I have alot of columns, so is there an easy way of doing that?

Comment: `COALESCE(cur.col_name, 'NULL')`

Comment: @lad2025 can you please explain this a little? if I want to put some other character/string if its null, then what?

Comment: COALESCE(cur.col_name, 'any string'). Please check documentation for COALESCE/NVL functions

Comment: Sometimes your client software will have this functionality.  E.g., in SQL\*Plus you could issue a `SET NULL` command to tell it how to display null values.  SQL\*Developer has a preference setting for the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than handle this requirement within PL/SQL, you should consider doing it in the cursor itself. In general, the more you can do in your SQL the better (The optimizer will handle the performance). Using lots of PL/SQL logic especially unnecessary if/else conditions in a loop will benefit you if you are processing a lot of data.

In your cursor you can simply:

```
CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT NVL(column, 'NULL')
FROM   dual;
```

There are plenty of in-built SQL functions that will handle this for you. Above, I used NVL, but you can use COALESCE, CASE, etc.

CASE example (note - if the column is not datatype VARCHAR then you will need to apply some datatype conversion to avoid any errors):

```
CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT (CASE 
           WHEN column IS NULL THEN
             'NULL'
           ELSE
             column
        END)
FROM   dual;
```

COALESCE example:

```
CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT COALESCE(column, 'NULL')
FROM   dual;
```

It's worth noting that NVL is a binary function, meaning only one column/value can be tested, however COALESCE can test multiple columns/values at the same time like below:

SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2, column3, 'NULL')
FROM   YOUR_TABLE;

In the case that column1 value is NULL and column2 is NOT NULL then column2 value will be returned.

If column1 and column2 values are both NULL then column3 value will be returned.

If column1, column2, column3 are all NULL then the value 'NULL' is returned.